# Jtable get selected row always returns -1

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem since yesterday.
I'v created a jTable with the WindowBuilder  in Eclipse and currently are trying to get the number of the selected row, by using the .getSelectedRow() function, but it is always returning -1 (no row selected), even when I have selected something.

This is my current code for testing the output:

```
public void checkActiveItem() {
        
        System.out.println(tableBills.getSelectedRow());
        
    }
```

I try to let it run this way trough a timer and at least that seems working:

```
Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Frontend f = new Frontend();
                f.checkActiveBill();
                f.checkActiveItem();
            }
        }, 250, 250 );
```

The table currently has just one entry, but even the first row dosn't get returned on selection.
I can create new rows by clicking add (and name them by entering a name in the textfield next to the add button before)

[image]

[image]

To create a new row I use this code, maybe there is the problem?

```
public void addBill() {
        //maybe need this value somewhere else to, so let -1 and +1 as it is
        int numbersOfBills = tableBills.getRowCount() - 1;
        Bill newBill = new Bill(txtBillName.getText(), numbersOfBills + 1);
        
        DefaultTableModel billModel2 = (DefaultTableModel) tableBills.getModel();
        int billNb = numbersOfBills + 1;
        
        billModel2.addRow(new Object[] {newBill.getBillNr(),newBill.getBillName(), newBill.getItemsInBill()});
    }
```

Comment: Creating `new Frontend()`s on each iteration of your timer, looks like the issue to me. So you are always calling `checkActiveItem()` on your newly created frontends. But since you didn't post a [mre], I can't help you further.

Comment: the function addBill() is  called on a button press.
Only the checkActiveBill() and therefore the getSelectedRow() functions are going to be called every 250ms, so I am not changing my frontend permanently.

Comment: "_I am not changing my frontend permanently._" - well, yes you are. Not the visible one, but the one you are calling the methods on. Looking at the code in the timer: `Frontend f = new Frontend()` <- This is the object you are calling `checkActiveItem()` on. However, this is not the one that you are seeing and pressing buttons on. So this is a completely different frontend, which does not have any rows added to it. But again, this is all I can make out, so please provide a [mre].

Comment: You are right, they are different objects of frontend. I completly missed that. Thanks, I was able to resolve the issue, you can post this as answer. The codes works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `-1` from `getSelectedRow()` even though you seem to have "added a row" is, because the `Frontend` object you are calling `checkActiveItem()` on is a completely different `Frontend` object than the one you are seeing.

The issue is here, inside of your `Timer`s `run()`:

```
Frontend f = new Frontend();
```

You create a new `Frontend` object for each timer iteration. And you call `checkActiveItem()` on exactly this object, not on the frontend you are seeing and pressing buttons on. Hence, the incorrect output.

As a solution, don't create new `Frontend`s, instead, call `checkActiveItem()` on your original frontend object, which you made visible.